# Null Returned by javaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

The code below runs perfectly on console but not when passed as a string in selenium javascript executor. Please help me.

Tried wrapping the complete script into function also but that didn't worked also.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); 
$("#pane-side span[class]").filter(function () {
    return regex.test($(this).text()); 
});
```

null provided by Javascriptexecutor.

Comment: Show us the exact code you used with `JavascriptExecutor`

Comment: <code>String searchNumberString = "function aaaa(){\n" + 
          "    var regex = new RegExp(\"^[0-9]+$\"); \n" + 
          "    var abc =$(\"#pane-side span[class]\").filter(function () {\n" + 
          "        return regex.test($(this).text()); \n" + 
          "    });\n" + 
          "    return abc;\n" + 
          "    };\n" + 
          "\n" + 
          "return aaaa();";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        List<WebElement> element =  (List<WebElement>) js.executeScript(searchNumberString);</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the javascript as shown below.

```
 var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); 
 return regex.test(document.querySelector("#pane-side span[class]").textContent);
```

Run this from selenium (python):

```
print(driver.execute_script('var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); return regex.test(document.querySelector("#pane-side span[class]").textContent);'))
```

**Output:**

`False` when span text "Hello"

`True` when span "123"

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Edit:**

Sample HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="pane-side">
  <span class="someclass">123</span>
 </div>

   <div id="pane-side">
  <span class="someclass2">no number</span>
 </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

**Jquery:**
[image]

Comment: can you site an example using jquery also??

Comment: Added jquery example, check and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: "function aaaa(){\n" + 
          "    var regex = new RegExp(\"^[0-9]+$\"); \n" + 
          "    var abc =$(\"#pane-side span[class]\").filter(function () {\n" + 
          "        return regex.test($(this).text()); \n" + 
          "    });\n" + 
          "    return abc;\n" + 
          "    };\n" + 
          "\n" + 
          "return aaaa();";

Comment: finally got the code working.thanks all for replying.

Comment: can you provide your jquery code as text also inplace gif?

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); regex.test($$("#pane-side span.someclass")[0].textContent);` and `var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]+$"); regex.test($$("#pane-side span.someclass2")[0].textContent);`.